# What does Class$S7119 signfy in GWT?

Tags: java, class, gwt, naming, anonymous-class

I'm getting the following error message in GWT:

> could not get type signature for class **Class$S7119**

What does this **Class$S7119** signify?

Anonymous classes have names like `SomeClass$1`, but I don't think that there are that many anonymous classes inside `java.lang.Class`. And if so, then no one starting with an S.

Comment: This is part of a SerializationException, isn't it?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I guess so, but  I don't know for sure, since I don't see any logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes in GWT only have full names (and other metadata such as superclass, package name, etc) if you leave that feature enabled. GWT has the capability to remove all of the class metadata, but doing so makes it hard to debug cases like this one.

Disable the 'disable class metadata' feature to see full names in your compiled JS. If you use maven, check the [`disableClassMetadata` flag](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#disableClassMetadata), if you build from ant or command line, look (and remove, or remove 'no') the [`-XnoclassMetadata` flag](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions).